# How to numpy.nan*0=0

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I would like to have python make the product

```
numpy.nan*0
```

return 0 (instead of nan), but e.g.

```
numpy.nan*4
```

still return nan.

My application: I have some numpy matrices which I am multiplying with one another. These contain many nan entries, and plenty of zeros.
The nans always represent unknown, but finite values which are known to become zero when multiplied with zero.
So I would like `A*B` return `[1,nan],[nan,1]` in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.matrix('1 0; 0 1')
B=np.matrix([[1, np.nan],[np.nan, 1]])
```

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: What must it return for `numpy.nan*4` i.e. something other than 0?

Comment: I want `numpy.nan*4=nan`

Comment: Are you looking for elementwise multiplication or matrix-mulitplication (one that involves sum-reduction)?

Comment: 'I've chosen NaN to represent something other than NaN and want it to behave differently in native arithmetic' seems like a tall order.

Comment: If the range of your actual numbers is reasonably limited you can pick something far outside it as a tag value representing your 'finite but unknown' and then replace the values touched by it after the multiplication.

Comment: @pvg how could this work in matrix multiplication where e.g. `1 + nan * 0` should result in 1?

Comment: @kazemakase the tag value would be a real number. so 1 + [tag value] * 0 would very much be 1.

Comment: @pvg doh, right.. stupid me. of course `*0` kills the tag :)

Comment: @kazemakase it's the right kind of thing to think about because the cases in which one might be able to get away with this are quite constrained. cases in which you can make nan * 0 = 0, though, are, I think, also 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the numpy function [numpy.nan_to_num()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix('1 0; 0 1')
B = np.matrix([[1, np.nan],[np.nan, 1]])
C = np.nan_to_num(A) * np.nan_to_num(B)
```

The outcome will be `[[1., 0.], [0., 1.]]`.

Comment: You won't be able to tell what your unknown values are, though, on the other end which I think is the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to override the behavior of `nan * 0` in numpy directly because that multiplication is performed at a very low level.

However, you can provide your own Python class with the desired multiplication behavior, but be warned: This will seriously kill performance.

```
import numpy as np


class MyNumber(float):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if other == 0 and np.isnan(self) or self == 0 and np.isnan(other):
            return 0.0
        return float(self) * other

def convert(x):
    x = np.asmatrix(x, dtype=object)  # use Python objects as matrix elements
    x.flat = [MyNumber(i) for i in x.flat]  # convert each element to MyNumber
    return x


A = convert([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
B = convert([[1, np.nan], [np.nan, 1]])

print(A * B)
# [[1.0 nan]
#  [nan 1.0]]
```